# structure tag option does not give tag name to field

Tags: json, go

In the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Profile struct {
    Username  string `json: "uname"`
    Followers int    `json:"followers,omitempty,string"`
}

type Student struct {
    FirstName string  `json:"fname"`
    LastName  string  `json:"lname,omitempty"`
    Email     string  `json:"-"`
    Age       int     `json:"-,"`
    IsMale    bool    `json:",string"`
    Profile   Profile `json:""`
}

func main() {
    john := &Student{
        FirstName: "John",
        LastName:  "",
        Age:       21,
        Email:     "john@doe.com",
        Profile: Profile{
            Username:  "johndoe91",
            Followers: 1975,
        },
    }

    johnJSON, _ := json.MarshalIndent(john, "", " ")
    fmt.Println(string(johnJSON))
}
```

---

`Username` does not get tag option `uname` as key name, as per the below output:

```
{
 "fname": "John",
 "-": 21,
 "IsMale": "false",
 "Profile": {
  "Username": "johndoe91",
  "followers": "1975"
 }
}
```

---

With the syntax:

```
type Profile struct {
    Username  string `json: "uname"`
    Followers int    `json:"followers,omitempty,string"`
}
```

Why `Username` does not have `uname` as key name in encoded JSON?

Comment: Language newbies are encouraged to use `go vet` a lot as it catches a lot of of simple mistakes.

Comment: And if you write even a single test, `go vet` will be run for you by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a space after `json:`, change it to

```
Username  string `json:"uname"`
```

Comment: Why does Go compiler does not pick this syntax error?

Comment: It's not a syntax error, any string is permitted as a tag.  They are made visible through reflection, and the `encoding/json` package happens to have a well defined spec for how they parse it, but as far as the spec goes, you could have `Username string "foo bar!!! xyz hi"` and it would be valid syntax

Comment: `go vet` catches things like this. It's turned on by default in the playground & editors like `VScode`: 
click `run` button here: https://play.golang.org/p/SNpFgIm-x2I